# Função mail() está chegando em linha

Tags: php, email

Estou tendo dificuldade na quebra de linha no corpo do email.
tentei varias forma e não consigo.

```
<?php  function enviarMensagem($dados) { 
                // Dados dos funcionarios 
$nome_usuario = $dados['nome']; 

$email_usuario = $dados['email']; 

$telefone_usuario = $dados['telefone'];

$assunto_usuario = $dados['subject'];

$mensagem_usuario = $dados['mensagem'];

// Criar variaveis de envio 
$destino = "marlonxm@hotmail.com";

$remetente = "http://www.marlonmarques.com.br/"; $assunto = "Mensagem do Site";

// Corpo do email 
$mensagem  = "Usuario(a) " . $nome_usuario . " mandou uma mensagem." . "</BR>"; 

$mensagem .= "email: " . $email_usuario . "</BR>";

$mensagem .= "Telefone: " . $telefone_usuario . "</BR>";

$mensagem .= "Assunto: " . "</BR>"; 

$mensagem .= $assunto_usuario . "</BR>"; 
$mensagem .= "Mensagem: " . "</BR>";
$mensagem .= $mensagem_usuario;
return mail($destino, $assunto, $mensagem, $remetente);
}
 ?>

Eu tentei vários jeitos na parte de mensagem e essas são as formas que tentei.

$mensagem  = "Usuario(a) " . $nome_usuario . " mandou uma mensagem." . "<BR/>"; 
$mensagem .= "email: " . $email_usuario . "<BR/>"; 
$mensagem .= "Telefone: " . $telefone_usuario . "<BR/>"; 
$mensagem .= "Assunto: " . "<BR/>"; 
$mensagem .= $assunto_usuario . "<BR/>"; 
$mensagem .= "Mensagem: " . "<BR/>";
$mensagem .= $mensagem_usuario;

===================================================================
$mensagem  = "Usuario(a) " . $nome_usuario . " mandou uma mensagem." . "\r\n";

$mensagem .= "email: " . $email_usuario . "\r\n"; 

$mensagem .= "Telefone: " . $telefone_usuario . "\r\n"; 

$mensagem .= "Assunto: " . "\r\n"; 

$mensagem .= $assunto_usuario . "\r\n"; 

$mensagem .= "Mensagem: " . "\r\n";

$mensagem .= $mensagem_usuario;

================================================




$mensagem  = "Usuario(a) " . $nome_usuario . " mandou uma mensagem." . "\r\n"; 

$mensagem .= "email: " . $email_usuario . "\r\n"; 

$mensagem .= "Telefone: " . $telefone_usuario . "\r\n"; 

$mensagem .= "Assunto: " . "\r\n"; 

$mensagem .= $assunto_usuario . "\r\n"; 

$mensagem .= "Mensagem: " . "\r\n";

$mensagem .= $mensagem_usuario;
$mensagem = nl2br($mensagem);
```

nenhuma dessas formas deu certo.
o email está chegando em linha.

Alguem pode ajudar com esse problema?

Comment: quis dizer que o email chegou tudo em uma linha? sem quebras de linha?

Comment: Exatamente... Está chegando tudo em linha. en não consigo resolver.